# apache mod rewrite rule iOS

Tags: ios, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently struggling with my Apache configuration with regards to iOS.
I would like to prevent users from directly accessing resources / files, e.g. jpg, png, mp4. But I want these images and videos to be still visible when embedded in my website.
I am opening the website in Safari and Chrome for iOS on iPhone and iPad.

So far I got it working pretty well using this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|mp4)$ - [F]
```

However, this is not working on iOS devices, where the embedded images and videos are not shown at all.

Has anyone got an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your Objective-C or Swift code?

Comment: I am opening the website using Safari and Chrome for iOS on an iPhone and iPad. I have edited my question.

Comment: You can debug the website by plugging the device into a Mac, then open the Safari. After enabling Developer Menu in Safari, you can debug the website in Mac's screen and show hidden errors. ( @masipcat this is not about iOS App. )

Comment: @Raptor Thank you. I get a 403 permission denied error. It seems that for some reason the browsers in iOS want to access the files directly, unlike desktop browsers...

Comment: You can further look into the Network tab, check the 403 Permission Denied item, and compare the `HTTP_REFERER` value with other files.